# Convexity of real diagonalizability

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $V$ be a real vector space of $n$ dimensional. 
$\mathrm{End}(V):=\left\{f:V\stackrel{\text{linear}}\to V\right\}$. 
Is the set
\begin{eqnarray}
Y:=\left\{ f\in\mathrm{End}(V)\ |\ \exists(\lambda_i)_{i=1}^n\subset\mathbb{R}\ , (e_i)_{i=1}^n\stackrel{\text{basis}}\subset V\text{ s.t. }fe_i=\lambda_i e_i \ (i=1,\cdots,n)\right\}
\end{eqnarray}
convex in $\mathrm{End}(V)$? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: No,

$$\left (\begin{array}{cc}0 &1 \\
0 &2
\end{array}\right ), \left (\begin{array}{cc}2 &1 \\
0 &0 
\end{array}\right ) $$

Comment: and neither is the complement, with a similar example.